# How to force an async task to wait for answer?

Tags: android, asynchronous, synchronous, openweathermap

I'm using an asynchronus library to get the weather forecast, but my code still goes on even if I haven't receive the informations about the weather. Is there any way to wait for the answer ? Or do you know anything that could help me with that ?

Answer (score 0):

The code goes on is fine. You should using callback to receive data. For more detail, please attach your function.

Comment: I'm using this library, how could I manage to do this ? https://github.com/igormatyushkin014/F32-for-Android

Comment: The result of request was called through callback therefore your code still goes on. Attach your code and I will help you fix it.

Comment: I've add it as an answer

Comment: When I try do get data, I create a new double. But on first launch, the double value is 0.0. But when I restart the activity, my value is the one I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

WeatherClass.java

```
public class WeatherClass {

    private static double temp = 0.0;


    public static double getTemp(double latitude, double longitude, Context context){
        String OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API = "xxxxxxxxx";
        new WeatherManager(OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API).getFiveDayForecastByCoordinates(latitude,longitude,
                new WeatherManager.ForecastHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceivedForecast(WeatherManager manager, Forecast forecast) {
                        // Handle forecast

                        List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                            long timestamp = forecast.getTimestampByIndex(i+3);
                            Weather weatherForTimestamp = forecast.getWeatherForTimestamp(timestamp);
                            Temperature tempMini = weatherForTimestamp.getTemperature().getMinimum();
                            double temperatureInCelcius = tempMini.getValue(TemperatureUnit.CELCIUS);
                            list.add(temperatureInCelcius);
                            Log.v("Weather", "" +weatherForTimestamp.getWind().getSpeed());
                            Log.v("Weather", "Température mini : " +  " "+ list.get(i));
                        }
                        int  minIndex = list.indexOf(Collections.min(list));
                        Log.v("Weather MINI", "Température mini : " + list.get(minIndex));
                        //Toast.makeText(context, "Température mini: " + list.get(minIndex), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        temp =  list.get(minIndex);
                        Log.v("WeatherClass", temp + "");




                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailedToReceiveForecast(WeatherManager manager) {
                        Log.v("TAG",  " ERREUR");
                        temp = -1000000;

                    }
                }
        );
        return temp;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code run:

1. Create a request to get data.
2. Return temp = 0.0
3. Receive data from server and update temp.

So you run your code will get return value = 0.0.

To fix it, you can do:

1. Create new Interface. 
   IResult.java

   ```
   public interface IResult {
       void onResult(double temp);
   }
   ```
2. Update getTemp method:

   ```
    public static void getTemp(double latitude, double longitude, final IResult callback){
           String OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API = "xxxxxxxxx";
           new WeatherManager(OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API)
           .getFiveDayForecastByCoordinates(latitude,longitude,
                   new WeatherManager.ForecastHandler() {
                       @Override
                       public void onReceivedForecast(WeatherManager manager, Forecast forecast) {
                           // Handle forecast

                           List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
                           for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                               long timestamp = forecast.getTimestampByIndex(i+3);
                               Weather weatherForTimestamp = forecast.getWeatherForTimestamp(timestamp);
                               Temperature tempMini = weatherForTimestamp.getTemperature().getMinimum();
                               double temperatureInCelcius = tempMini.getValue(TemperatureUnit.CELCIUS);
                               list.add(temperatureInCelcius);
                               Log.v("Weather", "" +weatherForTimestamp.getWind().getSpeed());
                               Log.v("Weather", "Température mini : " +  " "+ list.get(i));
                           }
                           int  minIndex = list.indexOf(Collections.min(list));
                           Log.v("Weather MINI", "Température mini : " + list.get(minIndex));
                           //Toast.makeText(context, "Température mini: " + list.get(minIndex), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                           temp =  list.get(minIndex);
                           Log.v("WeatherClass", temp + "");
                           callback.onResult(temp);



                       }

                       @Override
                       public void onFailedToReceiveForecast(WeatherManager manager) {
                           Log.v("TAG",  " ERREUR");
                           temp = -1000000;
                           callback.onResult(temp);

                       }
                   }
           );
       }
   ```
3. Use it

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       WeatherClass.getTemp(32.32, 322.3, new IResult() {
           @Override
           public void onResult(double temp) {
               //result here
           }
       });
   }
   ```

**Update**: Because the first launch, this method return 0.0 before updating temp (step 2 return temp, step 3 update temp), so you will get 0.0. The second launch, this method will return the result of first launch (because it return temp before updating temp), so you may think it right (but not right, return value is data of the first launch) .

Comment: Yes, I've just tried, it still returning me 0.0 on first launch. What can I do ? Thanks for your help anyway !

Comment: Did your log work right? Do you put your code in onResult method?

Comment: I don't see any error, and yes I put it in onResult method. I have a double in my MainActivity class, so in my onResult method, I've written : myDouble = temp;